# Any alternate approaches to calculate co-occurrence matrix in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I'm trying to calculate the co-occurrence matrix for a large corpus but it takes a very long time(+6hours). Are there any faster ways?

My approach:

consider this array as the `corpus` and each element of the corpus as `context`:

```
corpus = [
    'where python is used',
    'what is python used in',
    'why python is best',
    'what companies use python'
]
```

Algorithm:

```
words = list(set(' '.join(corpus).split(' ')))
c_matrix = np.zeros((len(words), len(words)), dtype='int')

for context in corpus:
    context = context.split(' ')
    for i in range(len(context)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(context)):
            row = words.index(context[i])
            column = words.index(context[j])
            c_matrix[row][column] += 1
```

Comment: It's unclear what you want. For the given corpus what is the expected matrix you want to have? and what does this matrix represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provided algorithm is not efficient because it recompute `words.index(...)` a lot of time. You can **pre-compute the indices** first and then build the matrix. Here is a significantly better solution:

```py
words = list(set(' '.join(corpus).split(' ')))
c_matrix = np.zeros((len(words), len(words)), dtype='int')

for context in corpus:
    context = context.split(' ')
    index = [words.index(item) for item in context]
    for i in range(len(context)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(context)):
            c_matrix[index[i]][index[j]] += 1
```

Moreover, you can transform `index` to a Numpy array and use **Numba** (or Cython) to build the `c_matrix` very quickly from `index`.

Finally, you can **transform `words` to a dictionary** (with the string in the current list as the dictionary keys and the index in the current list as the dictionary values) so that indexing will be much faster (constant-time fetch).

The resulting algorithm should be *several order of magnitude faster*. If this is not enough, then you probably need to replace the matrix `c_matrix` with a more advanced (but also much more complex) *sparse data-structure* regarding your needs.